# Regex matching any substring only after a delimiter

Tags: regex

How to define a regex that will match an exact string like this:
{VAR}

Or anything in this format:
{VAR:10}
{VAR:something}
... meaning if ":" is present, then accept anything to the right of it until the closing }.

So, it should NOT match this:
{VAR2} or {VAR3}, etc.

Right now I am using 2 separate regexes to search for the above 2 scenarios and would like to use one.

Comment: So, what is your current solution? What is wrong with it? What are your expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a bit crude, but I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
^{VAR(}|(:[A-Z0-9]+?)})$
```

This will take the start of the string as {VAR, then check if it either finds one of a } or a : followed by a series of numbers or uppercase characters until it finds a }.

Edit:
I didn't know that OP was looking for Anything after the character, so I have written a new version that will take any character.

```
^{VAR(}|(:.+)})$
```

Here is also a [Demo](https://regexr.com/49djk) of it.

Comment: Thanks much, I am using this now: {VAR}|{VAR:.*?} because I want to be able to accept ANYTHING (including special chars) between : and } - looks like that works, can you please confirm?

Comment: Ahh okay @cooper_milton. * probably isn't what you want, since * means 0 or more, so it would match {VAR:}. You would want to use + instead, which denotes 1 or more. I have added an edit if you'd like to use that instead.

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest reading up on lookaheads, look behinds, and the If-Then-Else construct. I recommend [this article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) at www.regular-expressions.info for a detailed explanation

The regex below should capture what you require

```
{VAR(?(?=:)[^}]*}|})
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l8jGIj/1)

The pattern starts with `{VAR`, as this is constant for all of your scenarios. 
We then leverage the if-then-else construct and a positive look ahead to check for a colon `(?(?=:)` and match everything up to and including the closing brace if a colon exists with `[^}]*}`. If a colon does not exist, the portion after the or | will only match a closing brace }.

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `{VAR}|(?<={VAR:)\w+(?=})`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5bmfSs/1)